# Automatic Refresh all posts at once

Tags: custom-field

I created a function to save custom fields on publish a post. Something like this.

```
function create_fields() {  
    global $post;     
    $casa_id = $post->ID;  
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'casa_id', $casa_id);  
}  
add_action('publish_post', 'create_fields');
```

This function saves on a custom field some string.

**Now the question**:

How can i use this action on older posts? I have 1000 posts and i don't want to refresh all the posts manually, **is this possible?**

Comment: I'm thoroughly confused as to why you want to save the post ID in the post's postmeta...

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1000,
    'post_type' => 'post'
    );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $casa_id = $post->ID;
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'casa_id', $casa_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: this didn't work.. Only refresh the last post, don't know why... I created another post to simplify the question. Do u have another solution? Thanks m8

Comment: what didn't work? can you explain? try changing posts_per_page to -1 and add 'post_type" => 'any' to args array

Answer (score 2):

It worked. I tryed this:

```
function actualiza() {  
global $post;  
$args = array(  
    'numberposts' => -1,  
    'post_type' => 'post',  
    );  
$the_query = get_posts( $args );  
if ($the_query) {  
    foreach ($the_query as $post) {  
        $name = $post->post_title;
            update_post_meta($post->ID, 'name_post', $name);
    } 
}
}   
wp_reset_query();  
add_action('wp_head', 'actualiza');
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this, the best solution that I found was this tool: https://github.com/mcguffin/acf-quick-edit-fields

This saved me an hour or two of manually updating 181 posts. After installing that plugin, I edited the ACF field and checked off the option “Allow editing this field in Bulk edit mode” then I was able to bulk edit the posts and update the field.