# Use update_post_meta to older posts

Tags: custom-field

It is possible to use the function **update_post_meta** on **older post?**

I have + 1000 posts and I need to update posts using update_post_meta but I'm affraid to do it one by one. Is there a simple way to **refresh all posts** with some function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatic Refresh all posts at once](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10140/automatic-refresh-all-posts-at-once)

Answer (score 1):

take a look at:

[Automatic Refresh all posts at once](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10140/automatic-refresh-all-posts-at-once/10143#10143)

its about the same question and the answer will do for you too.